Using "other words" instead of "in other words" in American English
In American English, can I use (write in a technical document) just "other words" instead of "in other words" in the beginning of a sentence? E.g., Other words, it was ...
I met "Other words, ..." in several texts, but I cannot understand how acceptable or widespread is this?

It's only one small word, so add in to make the meaning clearer and less slangy. P:S I've not come across this shorthand, maybe in IT circles it's quite the norm, but in standard English "other words" (additional words) is a different meaning to the one intended by the OP

If this is a fairly common occurrence in AmEng technical jargon, could you please cite and give links to two examples?

@Mari-LouA Other words, to continue without advertising services can be imposed.

@Mari-LouA Other words, the sites pay for themselves, and in addition, also bring a profit.

@Mari-LouA Other words, every human being must have access to water.

@Mari-LouA No, this is not something done here or anywhere. It is perceived to be an error, perhaps some confusion with otherwise.

@Mari-LouA I'm with you, I spent my entire career in electronics and software engineering and I'm lifelong avid reader. I can't recall any instance of seeing "in" omitted. As for Axel's examples, they all grate on my sensibilities because "in" is missing. I don't know where they come from.

@Mari-LouA As for me, it is like reduction of "at" in "At the same time, ..." -> "The same time, ..." in texts, but i'm not native speaker.

@axel your examples were found in the wild so to speak? Or did you make them up? I asked you to cite two instances, which means to tell us where you found these examples. Your three examples do not sound like idiomatic English.


When a question needs more details, use the "edit" button to add them to the question itself, rather than in comments. The comments aren't an official or permanent part of the question. 2) If possible, say where you found these examples. 3) Please also clarify what you mean by "technical document." It makes me think of a white paper or product manual, something publicly disseminated but limited in audience, but if you mean something more like an internal company memo or PowerPoint, that might be a different standard.


I edit IT material. I made it my business never to write Basically, To put it another way, or In other words - certainly not Other words. Because what follows - if simpler and better - needs to replace anything earlier, not add more layers: "As a result, the system can impose continuing without advertising services."

There are a few true hits for this in COCA when searching "PUNC other words" including in the book Bleachers:

"Mona is very fertile."
"Evidently. How does she look?"
"She looks pregnant."
"I mean, you know, is she in shape?"
"Other words, is she fat?"

However, there was not a single hit that wasn't from spoken English (or dialogue like above). I would not omit the preposition except in the most casual of discourse (which does not include technical documents).
